# Slick Slider. Sync two sliders to one custom append dots

Tags: jquery, carousel, slick.js

I have two sliders that are synced with the except for the custom appended dots. Ideally, I need the custom dots to act as navigation for both sliders. Currently, the dots only work for the slider it is appended to.

```
//*** Slick Stuff */

if ($(".masthead-content-slider").length > 0) {
    $('.masthead-content-slider').slick({
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        infinite: true,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 10000,
        speed: 1000,
        fade: true,
        cssEase: 'ease',
        draggable: false,
        dots: true,
        arrows: false,
        asNavfor: '.masthead-image-slider',
        appendDots: $('.slick-dots-masthead')
    }); 
}

if ($(".masthead-image-slider").length > 0) {
    $('.masthead-image-slider').slick({
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        infinite: true,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 10000,
        speed: 1000,
        fade: true,
        cssEase: 'ease',
        draggable: false,
        dots: false,
        arrows: false,
        asNavfor: '.masthead-content-slider'
    }); 
}

$('.prev').click(function(){
    $('.masthead-content-slider').slick('slickPrev');
    $('.masthead-image-slider').slick('slickPrev');
});

$('.next').click(function(){
    $('.masthead-content-slider').slick('slickNext');
    $('.masthead-image-slider').slick('slickNext');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is due to a typo.

```
asNavfor: '.masthead-content-slider'
```

should be

```
asNavFor: '.masthead-content-slider'
```